# Select Statements SQLite and iOS

Tags: ios, sqlite

I have an app that takes input from a text field and puts it into a string.  I have a table with a field in it that I want to check the value of the string from the input against the value in the field in the database.  I'm new to iOS and fairly new to SQLite.  Here's what I have:

```
NSString *strStoreNumber;
strStoreNumber = StoreNumber.text; // StoreNumber is the text field
querystring = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT string FROM tblStore WHERE string = ;"];
```

After "WHERE string = " I want it to check the value of strStoreNumber against the value in the "string" field in the database.  Please let me know if this is not clear enough.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is about string creation:

```
querystring = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT string FROM tblStore WHERE string = %@;", strStoreNumber];
```

More details on [String Format Specifiers](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html).

Comment: Ah, I should have known better.  I have some familiarity with the C language, but OBj-C/iOS/SQLite is all pretty new to me.  Thanks again for the help, my friend.